# Related record display fields that is not included in the layout and Account name has no label

Tags: lightning-record-page, relatedrecord

I'm added a Account Related Record on the Contact Record Page but it displays some field which is not included in the layout and the Account name has no label. It only happens if the User has a Read Only access on the account. Does anyone knows how to fix this without giving Edit access? Any help is appreciated. Forgive my grammar. Thanks!

Layout:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Expected Result (but View Only):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user doesn't have Edit access on the object, the fields are rendered using the compact layout , as explained here -

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380203&type=1